# mysql get distinct tokens from a string list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query in `mysql` that `group concats` records and gives a value having redundant tokens. Below is the output of the query:

```
Problem Area->ACC-HO->ACC-HO->Credit Note (C/N)->Problem description ->Problem description
```

But I want the distinct tokens of this string as below

```
Problem Area->ACC-HO->Credit Note (C/N)->Problem description
```

Is there a way to do this in the sql `SELECT` query itself?

**EDIT** 
Here is [schema and query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8b02/3)
Below is my query:

```
SELECT 
t2.transaction_id AS transaction_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(
CONCAT(
 t1.display_text,
 '->',
   (CASE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mst_node a WHERE a.parent_node_id = t1.node_id))
      WHEN 1 THEN t1.display_text ELSE 
      (SELECT b.display_text AS DISPLAY FROM mst_node b 
      WHERE parent_node_id = t2.node_id AND b.display_seq = t2.entered_value) 
     END)
     ) 
  ORDER BY t2.logtime_stamp SEPARATOR '->'
) AS display_text 
FROM

mst_node t1 
  JOIN trn_user_log t2 
    ON t1.app_id = t2.app_id AND t1.node_id = t2.node_id     
WHERE (t1.app_id = 105) 
  AND t1.parent_node_id IS NOT NULL 
  AND t1.save_as_default IS NULL 
GROUP BY transaction_id,
  mobile_no 
ORDER BY t2.transaction_id DESC,
  t2.logtime_stamp,
  t2.mobile_no
```

Comment: You know that you don't need all those ugly backticks?

Comment: :-) yes i know... mysql client..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve my issue by using a `UNION` of two select queries and then doing a `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT column ORDER BY another_column)`.

Below is the query I used:

```
SELECT 
transaction_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT display_text ORDER BY logtime_stamp SEPARATOR '->') AS display_text
FROM
 (SELECT 
  t2.transaction_id AS transaction_id,
  t2.logtime_stamp,
  t1.display_text AS display_text 
  FROM mst_node t1 
  JOIN trn_user_log t2 ON t1.app_id = t2.app_id 
   AND t1.node_id = t2.node_id 
   WHERE (t1.app_id = 105) 
   AND t1.parent_node_id IS NOT NULL 
   AND t1.save_as_default IS NULL 
  UNION
 SELECT t2.transaction_id AS transaction_id,t2.logtime_stamp,
  CASE(NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mst_node a WHERE a.parent_node_id = t1.node_id)) 
  WHEN 1 THEN NULL 
  ELSE (SELECT b.display_text AS display_text FROM mst_node b WHERE parent_node_id = t2.node_id AND b.display_seq = t2.entered_value) 
  END AS display_text
FROM   mst_node t1 JOIN trn_user_log t2 
      ON t1.app_id = t2.app_id AND t1.node_id = t2.node_id    
  WHERE (t1.app_id = 105) 
  AND t1.parent_node_id IS NOT NULL 
  AND t1.save_as_default IS NULL 
  ORDER BY transaction_id DESC,logtime_stamp
  ) AS T 
  GROUP BY transaction_id 
  ORDER BY transaction_id DESC,logtime_stamp
```

Answer (score 5):

In you `GROUP CONCAT` add `DISTINCT` so it will only concatenate unique values.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colName),....
FROM   ...
WHERE  ...
GROUP BY ...
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8fa6/7)

Comment: I have added the schema and query as a link to the sqlFiddle. Kindly check now...

Answer (score 0):

in your grouping clause, you can add another `group by` to group by this string column as well.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(myStringColumn),....
FROM   ...
WHERE  ...
GROUP BY myOtherColumn,myStringColumn
```

Comment: that doest work, it will create another row if there is another value of `myStringColumn` on `myOtherColumn`. Try it.

Comment: :( Bad guess by me,I will delete this answer in few minutes.